# Open Borders option not available

Tags: endless-space, endless-space-disharmony

I'm playing Endless Space (with Disharmony), and I'm slightly confused by the diplomacy mechanics. I've made peace with another faction (Horatio, if it matters; I'm Sophons myself). I'd like to offer them to open borders, but when the option is greyed out in the menu, and if I hover over it, I get

> The terms you request cannot be fulfilled.

Now I know they also need to have researched that diplomacy option, but I *know* they've got the Relativistic Markets tech, because I gave it to them.

What other requirements are there to open borders with another faction?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* that they need to discover at least one of your systems before you can get open borders with them.
I had the same problem and could only open borders when one of their scouts entered my system through a bordering wormhole.

Source: personal experience

Comment: I think I had come to the conclusion that I needed to wait a number of turns (7? 10?) after making peace before I was able to open borders, but I haven't played the game enough to confirm this (which is why I didn't get back to this post). Your observation sounds like a possibility, too, though. I'll keep an eye out for that!

Comment: I'm almost certain that @MartinBüttner is right, and you simply need to wait a few turns. Also, I don't think they don't need to have it researched. If you need to wait a few turns, it should show the number of turns left on the diplomacy screen when you are trying to talk to that empire. Something like "Peace (3 turns)" meaning you still have 3 turns after declaring peace before you can change your diplomatic status again.